# Viewing Notes on the Noteboard in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

Is there a setting that needs to be changed so I see notes from other users on documents/folders in the SharePoint 2013 Tag/Notes Note-board?

I am selecting the document that I know someone else has added a note to, selecting the File tab, selecting Tags & Notes and then selecting Note-board, but there are no notes visible from other users.  I have searched the internet and sites only give directions about how to add a Note.

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing the notes on the news feed? do you have any MYSite in your farm and make sure MMS associate with it.

**Understanding permissions and privacy for notes**

Notes are public. People can see notes you write on someone’s profile page and in your recent activities, whether or not they are following you as a colleague. If someone is following you or the person you are writing the note to as a colleague, they can also see the note in their Newsfeed.

You can delete notes, so that they no longer appear with the content or on someone’s profile. However, the text of the note is not deleted from someone’s Newsfeed, for example, if they are following you or the note’s recipient as a colleague.

also check this link

http://www.technospot.net/blogs/tags-notes-and-i-like-it-social-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: I found on https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-2013-Keywords-tags-and-hash-tags.aspx that I needed to add /_layouts/15/thoughts.aspx to be able to see my newsfeed.  I'm wanting to see other users comments on specific documents stored in Sharepoint that they have posted on Noteboard.  I thought that I should be able to see them when I select Tags & Notes for that specific document.